# Realtek Wifi-adapter not found on ubuntu 20.04 install

Tags: 20.04, wireless, realtek-wireless

I recently got a laptop (lenovo legion pro 5). After dual booting with linux 20.04.6 LTS, my system does not detect any wifi adapter. So, I followed the common steps that I mostly found for addressing wifi not found issue for realtek wifi-adapters on this forum as below:

```
sudo apt update 
sudo apt -y install git build-essential linux-headers-generic
git clone https://github.com/lwfinger/rtw89.git
cd rtw89
make
sudo make install
sudo modprobe rtw89pci
```

Even after following the steps, I get the following error:

```
anshul@anshul-Legion-Pro:~$  sudo dmesg | grep -e 8852 -e rtw
[    1.513903] rtw89core: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel.
[    1.514008] rtw89core: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel
[    1.583389] rtw89_8852ce 0000:04:00.0: Direct firmware load for rtw89/rtw8852c_fw.bin failed with error -2
[    1.583392] rtw89_8852ce 0000:04:00.0: failed to early request firmware: -2
[    1.583463] rtw89_8852ce 0000:04:00.0: Direct firmware load for rtw89/rtw8852c_fw.bin failed with error -2
[    1.584192] rtw89_8852ce 0000:04:00.0: failed to wait firmware completion
[    1.584212] rtw89_8852ce 0000:04:00.0: failed to setup chip information
[    1.584465] rtw89_8852ce: probe of 0000:04:00.0 failed with error -22
[    2.517580] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: examining hci_ver=0c hci_rev=000c lmp_ver=0c lmp_subver=8852
[    2.517583] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: unknown IC info, lmp subver 8852, hci rev 000c, hci ver 000c
```

Can anyone please help me with this issue?

Regards
Anshul

Comment: You've not provided details as to what Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS product you installed (*thus we don't know what stack you're using, as different product/ISOs default to different stacks*) so please be specific. Were there errors in the second command you provided (*accepting before you read due to `-y`*) as you may not have included all required packages to switch to the GA kernel stack if that was what you attempted to do (*your kernel stack is unknown as you didn't specify, nor provide product details*). I'd suggest reading the output of the commands you provided.

Comment: I believe the README that is included in the rtw89 directory explains how to download and install the required firmware. Do you need a step-by-step? Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.